# Redux-saga add additional field for POST body

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to POST request using redux-saga. I have form of two inputs. I am using selector to gather input data from form, for now it is my body. But I need to add itemId, which is not typed in by user. How should I insert it in body?

My saga looks like:

```
export function* submitForm() {
  try {
    const formType = 'item';
    const body = yield select(makeSelectModifiedData());
    let requestURL;

    switch (formType) {
      case 'item':
        requestURL = 'http://localhost:1587/item';
        break;
      default:
    }

    const response = yield call(request, requestURL, { method: 'POST', body });

    if (response.itemId) {
      yield call(forwardTo, '/item');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.error('Error message...', {
      html: false,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: use body.itemId = set any value

Comment: @AmruthLS, could you show me little example, because I am trying this all day. I am using selector and there is a full completed json object.

Comment: i mean after this line     const body = yield select(makeSelectModifiedData());
body.itemId =5 like this

Comment: @AmruthLS, it doesn't take the value.

Comment: if not change `const body` to `let body`

Comment: @AmruthLS, No. It works with let, thank you very much!

Comment: @AmruthLS, it's working, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append itemId to body.

```
    let body = yield select(makeSelectModifiedData());
    body.itemId = 5;//provide id here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
export function* submitForm() {
  try {
    const formType = 'item';
    const myFormValues = yield select(makeSelectModifiedData());
    const body = {
      ...myFormValues,
      itemId: myItemId
    };
    let requestURL;

    switch (formType) {
      case 'item':
        requestURL = 'http://localhost:1587/item';
        break;
      default:
    }

    const response = yield call(request, requestURL, { method: 'POST', body });

    if (response.itemId) {
      yield call(forwardTo, '/item');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.error('Error message...', {
      html: false,
    });
  }
}
```